# How to create personalized font in Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

Is there any other way to create a very own personalized font or character in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fontforge/). From the Fontforge project page:

> FontForge allows you to edit outline and bitmap fonts. You may create
>   new ones or modify old ones.

If you just want to install some crazy fonts that other people have created, have look at almost any [truetype fonts you can find](http://www.fonts101.com/search/crazy) with google.

Comment: Thanks Hakeem, but FontForge is not what I'm looking for. What I meant for personalized fort is to transformed letter, like A = :) or a = :( sort of. But I like much more if I can change letters into different characters like an alien letters from the movies. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Actually Fontforge would appear to be exactly what you are asking for to "create personalised fonts".  I've edited the answer to add more information.

Comment: I agree with fabricator4. FontForge is the primary way in Linux to do what the OP asked for. If it doesn't suit the needs of @obetus, he/she should edit the question to clarify it. +1